# Missing type Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder

Tags: c#, asp.net

My project won't build because of the following error:

> Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported.

What reference do I need to add?

Comment: First hit in google: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.runtimebinder.binder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thank you to Alex. Add a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp`.